# Show that the devil's staircase function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the devil's staircase function $\mathcal{D}:[0,1]\to [0,1]$.

Show that $\mathcal{D}$ is measureable.

I feel like this is obvious but the proof escapes my mind.

Can I get some help in approaching this problem?

Comment: Monotone functions are measurable, which has a two line proof.

Comment: You have not defined any function...

Comment: Continuous functions are measurable.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DevilsStaircase.html

Answer (score 4):

The Cantor function  is monotone,isn't it? I hope you don't need a proof of that. Note that $[0,1]$ itself is a measurable set, as it is a Borel set.

As to why monotone functions are measurable, note that the left and right limits for every point exist for a monotone function , but they may not be equal, in which case you can find a rational number between the limits. Thus the number of discontinuity points is at most as many as the rational numbers, which is a countable set and hence of measure zero. It follows that monotone functions are continuous almost everywhere, and hence not just measurable, but also Riemann integrable. Thus, the Cantor function is measurable and Riemann integrable, and it's integral over the interval $[0,1]$ is one-half.